# Possibility of a Web App to act as a Bluetooth Low Energy Beacon for BLE advertising?

Tags: web, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth, eddystone-url

I've been taking a look into the documents from https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/
and it seems nearly all of the samples demos or codes is mostly the web app acting as a central. I'm looking to know if there's a possible way to utilize the codes in someway to make my web app to be a peripheral or if.... there's a peripharel simulator out there based as a webapp. The closest i found is based as an android app.

I'm looking at the possibility to actually implement it into a PWA.

Thanks a bunch for taking the time to read!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [specification page](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) it says the following:

> The first version of this specification allows web pages, running on a UA in the Central role, to connect to GATT Servers over either a BR/EDR or LE connection.

The project has created a [peripheral simulator](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/ble-test-peripheral-android) which is written as an Android app so probably confirms why you haven't found any examples.